# Логика платного тестирования

Tags: php, yii, тестирование, javascript

Здравствуйте. Нужно организовать следующее:

1. Оплату тестирования при запросе результата этого тестирования.
2. Оплату за час пользования тестированием.
   Это два разных вида тестирования.

Какую логику вы бы мне посоветовали? Особенно заботит то как и где (в бд или куках?) хранить данные о том, что пользователь оплатил результат или время. Использую YII поэтому спрошу коснется ли это как то `RBAC`, `CWebUser` или др. стандартных средств фреймворка.

Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

В куках ничего важнее id сессии хранить нельзя, тк куки хранятся на стороне клиента(легко редактируются) и найдется такой человек, кто будет менять "результат оплаты", как ему вздумается. Только на сервере(бд).

Comment: С БД понятно. Тогда можно ли хранить данные о том , что статус пользователя "оплачен" в сессиях ведь они тоже хранятся на сервере? Было бы очень удобно для меня. Иначе придется лезть в базу и постоянно удалять временные данные.

Comment: Сохраняйте данные в БД, меняйте нужное поле в сессии, потом при необходимости выполнения какого-то ответственного действия проверяйте, не изменилось ли это поле в БД.

Comment: Как только человек "залогинился" по с помощью куков или прямым вводом логина\пароля: сразу выкатываейте на него все важные данные из базы в массив и в нем работайте. Если что-то меняется, меняйте в первую очередь в базе(!), а потом уже в массиве. А так БД на то и есть что ьы в неё "лазить".